# Can someone explain why they omitted 'of the' in the second second sentence after the word 'majority'?

Tags: grammar, expressions, meaning-in-context, parts-of-speech, sentence-meaning

1. A Vast Majority of the World’s Population Breathes Unsafe Air
2. But the truth is that as it stands at the moment the majority population do not believe this.

Comment: Probably because their referring to that part of the population that is "in the majority".  Eg, the white population in the US.  Would need to see the context to say with any certainty, though.

Comment: @Hot Licks "**their**"? It's falling apart, Hot Licks. The whole lot's going.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - They're, their now, don't have a calf!!

Comment: Where do these sentences come from?

Comment: They are from random news websites